# Permission denied while pushing source to github

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repository from github and cloned it to my local directory. I have also added a remote source to my repository by
using the command `git remote set-url origin http://giturl`
I checked out a branch from the remote branch and got the updated source code.
Now when I try to push my changes to my local repository using `git push origin branchname` it says I do not have permission 
to push to the remote repository.

Comment: Can you post the output of ```git remote -v```
My guess is you're trying to push to github (and that fails because of missing ssh-key setup)

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard It gives the origin as my remote github link for both push and fetch. I want to push to my local repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion you could add another remote, for example:

`git remote add local-repo git@host`

Source: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/

And then you can commit like this:

`git push local-repo master`

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote set-url origin http://giturl
```

This command modifies the current URL the remote `origin` points on. If you cloned your repository from github, it was already good and you didn't need to modify it.

You may want to change the remote URL by issuying the same command, replacing the `http://giturl` by what you've put behind `git clone`.

Comment: The source from where I cloned is my original source code. The remote once is where another another developer is working from. I wanted the changes he had before it is merged to the main code